# Pagenumbering starts with 2 after \KOMAoptions{open=left}

Tags: page-numbering, koma-script

im writing my bachelors-thesis using Latex with scrbook and have the folowing problem:
After my Titlepage and some other Stuff I changed the to open=left

```
\KOMAoptions{open=left}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

That leaves me with the first page of my 2 page long table of contents on the left side, but page number ii. If I set the counter as {0} the second page will be i. Same goes for the \mainmatter.
This means the pages start on the left, but numbering still starts on the right. What can I do about that?

Thank you very much,
Marlin

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. Unlike many other programming languages, it makes a lot of difference if you change the preamble of your document in terms of the output, such as clashing packages or page settings changed by some detail in the code and so on. That's why we need to have a complete example together with the relevant parts of your preamble included.

Comment: Why are you using `\clearpage`? Isn't this the reason for your phantom page ?

Comment: Look in any (English, German, ...) book: Left pages have always an even page number.

Answer (score 3):

KOMA-Script is well prepared to build books with a good typography.

I had until now not to use the KOMA-Option `\KOMAoptions{open=left}`.

Because you gave us only a code snippet and no MWE, I show you with the following MWE how you can use the build in commands of KOMA-Script to create a book.

If there is still the need to use your option please copy my MWE, add your commands you need, and edit your question and add the new MWE to show us, what you want. BTW: I took an german MWE thats the reason you will see some german words, but for you the layout is more important I guess?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
  english
% ngerman
 ,paper=a4 
 ,fontsize=11pt 
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{scrpage2}       % headers and Footers
\usepackage{lipsum}         % for dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter                  % Vorspann des Dokuments
\title{Titel des Dokuments}
\author{Vorname Nachname}
\subtitle{Untertitel des Dokuments}
\publishers{Herausgeber}

\uppertitleback{Test}
\lowertitleback{Testerle}
\extratitle{Extratitel des Dokuments}

\dedication{Widmung}

\maketitle                    % Erzeugung der Titelseiten

%\KOMAoptions{open=left}      % I guess you want it here ????

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\tableofcontents              % Inhaltsverzeichnis hier einfügen

\mainmatter                   % Hauptteil des Dokuments
\chapter{Eins, engl. One}
\lipsum

\chapter{Ein Beispiel, engl. An Example}
\lipsum

\backmatter                   % Schlußteil des Buches
\appendix

\chapter{Kapitel im Anhang, engl. Chapter in Appendix}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```